# Parsing block comments with Megaparsec using symbols for start and end

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I want to parse text similar to this in Haskell using Megaparsec.

```
# START SKIP
def foo(a,b):
    c = 2*a # Foo 
    return a + b
# END SKIP
```

, where `# START SKIP` and `# END SKIP` marks the start and end of the block of text to parse.

Compared to [skipBlockComment](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.0.0/docs/src/Text-Megaparsec-Lexer.html#skipBlockComment) I want the parser to return the lines between the start and end marker.

This is my parser.

```
skip :: Parser String
skip = s >> manyTill anyChar e
  where s = string "# START SKIP"
        e = string "# END SKIP"
```

The `skip` parser works as intended.

To allow for a variable amount of white space within the start and end marker, for example `#    START   SKIP` I've tried the following:

```
skip' :: Parser String
skip' = s >> manyTill anyChar e
  where s = symbol "#" >> symbol "START" >> symbol "SKIP"
        e = symbol "#" >> symbol "END" >> symbol "SKIP"
```

Using `skip'` to parse the above text gives the following error.

```
3:15:
unexpected 'F'
expecting "END", space, or tab
```

I would like to understand the cause of this error and how I can fix it.

Comment: The problem is you have a common prefix for your parsers. Take a look at [`try`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.1.1/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:try).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Alec already commented, the problem is that as soon as `e` encounters `'#'`, it counts as a *consumed character*. And the way parsec and its derivatives work is that as soon as you've consumed any characters, you're committed to that parsing branch – i.e. the `manyTill anyChar` alternative is then not considered anymore, even though `e` ultimately fails here.

You can easily request backtracking though, by wrapping the end delimiter in [`try`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.1.1/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:try):

```
skip' :: Parser String
skip' = s >> manyTill anyChar e
  where s = symbol "#" >> symbol "START" >> symbol "SKIP"
        e = try $ symbol "#" >> symbol "END" >> symbol "SKIP"
```

This then will before consuming `'#'` set a “checkpoint”, and when `e` fails later on (in your example, at `"Foo"`), it will act as if no characters had matched at all.

In fact, traditional parsec would give the same behaviour also for `skip`. Just, because looking for a string and only succeeding if it matches *entirely* is such a common task, megaparsec's `string` is implemented like `try . string`, i.e. if the failure occurs within that fixed string then it will always backtrack.

However, compound parsers still don't backtrack by default, like they do in attoparsec. The main reason is that if anything can backtrack to any point, you can't really get a clear *point of failure* to show in the error message.

Comment: Thank you @leftaroundabout! Very nice explanation.